# Conflict with if conditionals

Tags: javascript

I´m new in javascript, I have two if conditions like:

```
if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial){
    sCumplimiento  = 'Si'
}else{
    sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}

if(fieldStatus === "4"){
    sCumplimiento  = 'Si'
}else{
    sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}
```

Problem is only second condition execute why it occurs?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "second condition"? Which statement exactly is executed for you? Also, what are the values of `currentServerDateTime`, `sCumplimientoInicial` and  `fieldStatus`?

Comment: The second part will pretty much make the first part irrelevant since it's overwriting the variable no matter what

Comment: If you are referring to the `fieldStatus === "4"` is the one running then you are just overwriting your variables.

Comment: `currentServerDateTime` and `sCumplimientoInicial` are dates, If I execute it without my second if condition it runs correctly, but when I add second if conditional: `if(fieldStatus === "4"){` only this one take effect on my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Problem is only second condition execute why it occurs?

No, they both execute, but you're overwriting the result of the first one with the result of the second. Example:

```js
var currentServerDateTime = new Date(2017, 0, 1);
var sCumplimientoInicial = new Date(2017, 0, 2);
if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial){
    sCumplimiento  = 'Si'
}else{
    sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}
console.log("sCumplimiento after first if/else: ", sCumplimiento);

var fieldStatus = "3";

if(fieldStatus === "4"){
    sCumplimiento  = 'Si'
}else{
    sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}
console.log("sCumplimiento after second if/else: ", sCumplimiento);
```

If you mean for the result to be `'Si'` **only** if both conditions are true, you would combine the two conditions:

```
if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial && fieldStatus === "4") {
    sCumplimiento  = 'Si'
}else{
    sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}
```

Of course, it could be you need to combine them in some other way; for instance, if it should be `'Si'` if *either* condition is true ("or" rather than "and"):

```
if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial || fieldStatus === "4") {
    sCumplimiento  = 'Si'
}else{
    sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}
```

...regardless, the fundamental answer is that `sCumplimiento` needs to be set only once, not twice.

Or if you need both results, you'll need two variables, not one, to hold them.

Comment: Problem is that second conditional can be in the same if  because I want  `sCumplimiento  = 'Si'` if my first if is true and I want `sCumplimiento  = 'Si'` if `fieldStatus === "4"` independiently of first if

Comment: @Ledwing: What **exactly** are the rules for making it `'Si'` vs. `'No'`? From what you've said above, it *might* be that you wan `if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial || fieldStatus === "4") {` ("or" rather than the "and" in the answer above), but...

Comment: I dont have an idea we can use or clause like c#, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on code that you've pasted here, the two conditions fill the same variable: `sCumplimiento`.

So, the second `if` block will override the first one.

What you code need to do, exactly?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need to run two conditions but not override first one

Comment: `if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicia || fieldStatus === "4"){
    sCumplimiento  = 'Si'
}else{
    sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}`

should work :)